# Unable to fetch custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress

We're using custom fields to send data onto the required php template pages. Anyways all is working fine.
We are using revolution slider for the slider and showing slider aliases as options in the custom field to pick when we're editing posts, events, pages etc..

The slider choice they're picking is then sent to the header, where we are loading the revolution slider shortcode. Its a quire simple mechanism.

However, the slider short code custom field is sending its value from ALL pages, posts except for the the event-categories. its a custom taxonomy.

in the header.php of the theme, I have a variable that gets the custom field's choice value using the following function:

```
    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mycustomfield', true );
```

I'm assuming that its getting the meta from posts, pages and everywhere else except for the taxonomy term.I'm guessing i will have to create a new variable and use a different expression to get the custom field's data. So can you help me with this please?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually checked your database to see where the custom field value is stored? Because if it is a custom taxonomy, you cannot get the value using "get_post_meta". You will have to use something like [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

I had a lot of confusion regarding this. Only way to be certain, is to check the database and see where the value is being stored: wp_postmeta or wp_term*.

Comment: I'm using the advanced custom fields plugin so does that give you a conclusion?

Comment: I think you should try out the function I mentioned. Just test it to check if it is returning anything (use it as a template tag in your post page template). This function should return all the taxonomy terms associated with the post.

Answer (score 0):

the way you get ACF custom fields is not the same way as wp fields.

```
<?php the_field($field_name, $post_id); ?>
```

[ACF the field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)